# Use of frame_max in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I've read about the frame_max for rabbitMQ, it said frame_max is "Maximum permissible size of a frame (in bytes) to negotiate with clients. Setting to 0 means "unlimited" but will trigger a bug in some QPid clients. Setting a larger value may improve throughput; setting a smaller value may improve latency."

Why the default value is 128 KB. I think in production environment, there is no case in which one wants to have high latency, then why the default value is set so much low. It can be set by default as very high, so as one can have high throughput always. Is there any harm in having high value by default ??? Also, beyond what value is the frame_max behaves as if it is zero i.e. unlimited, which can trigger a bug in QPid clients....

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't need to change this value.

Second, `frame_max` sets a size of chunks, a unit of multiplexing. It's used to avoid a situation when a single channel can saturate the whole connection. If you publish few big messages, on different AMQP channels, they will be multiplexed. Smaller messages at the same time will be able to move through.

Actually, better concurrency could be achieved by using multiple connections but that's a different story.

Comment: I couldnot understand that how the messages are passed via the frames. 
i)Is it that, only 1 frame is alloted to each message(message size<frame_max) OR is it that in a single frame if large number of messages can fit, all of them will be stored in that frame ? 
ii)Why are you saying that we shouldnot be changing frame_max. If we know that the size of message can be at max , say 2 MB, then aint it safe to keep frame_max as 2 MB ? Since, using frame_max as 256 KB for messages of large size, the producer's throughput will be reduced by significant amount .

Comment: "the producer's throughput will be reduced by significant amount" - define "significant amount". It would be best if you took a look at AMQP 0-9-1 spec, as it does clearly defines how the AMQP framing works.