# Why does my default RabbitMQ config have such low throughput?

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, kibana

### Background

I'm setting up an [Elastic Search ELK stack](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/) for real-time log analysis using RabbitMQ as the broker.  I am shipping my log files to RabbitMQ using a python project called [Beaver](http://beaver.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/usage.html).  Things to take note are:

- Using `exchange_type: "direct"`
- Using `queue_durable: 1` (not sure if this is worth mentioning)
- Using `exchange_durable: 1` (not sure if this is worth mentioning)

### RabbitMQ

I downloaded the newest RabbitMQ from their website and ran it using the `rabbitmq.config` file.  The only thing I included in the config file was:

- tcp_listeners -> {"0.0.0.0", 5672}
- loopback_users -> [] (allow guest user to connect remotely)
- frame_max -> 2155000 **explained below**

I am parsing [netscreen](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/screenos/information-products/pathway-pages/netscreen-series/product/) log files and log entry is roughly 431 bytes.  I multiplied this by 5000 and hence arrived at the frame_max value.

On the consumer side of things (logstash rabbitmq input plugin) I have the following setup:

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        host => "rabbitmq server ip here"
        queue => "indexer-queue"
        exchange => "logstash-exchange"
        key => "logstash-routing-key"
        exclusive => false
        durable => true
        auto_delete => false
        type => "logstash-indexer-input"
        prefetch_count => 2000
        threads => 5
    }
}
```

This setup was recommended [here](http://blog.lusis.org/blog/2012/01/31/load-balancing-logstash-with-amqp/).

### Problem

When I fired up everything, I realized that I was only able to achieve a maximum of 300 or so messages per second.  Both the produce and consume values are 300 messages/second.  I am assuming this means that whatever is produced is consumed immediately.  Looking at the queue, it is mostly empty.

Comparing this with Redis, RabbitMQ is pathetic in terms of throughput.  I heard great reviews about RabbitMQ, in particular its speed.

**Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my setup?  Why am I only achieving 300+ messages/second with RabbitMQ rather than 3500 messages/second with Redis?**

Comment: Why do you need to change the frame_max value? This answer here is by a former RabbitMQ developer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576576/342013

Comment: Does queued messages number growing?

Comment: @old_sound OK,  I only changed it because I thought it would increase my throughput, but it didn't work either.   I'll change it back to its default value then.

Comment: How do I tell if queued messages number is growing?

Comment: You can inspect queue length and other values using the management plugin which has an HTTP API

Comment: @Mark I'm running into the same issue -- only about 300 messages/sec.  Did you ever find solution?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using rabbitmq too, I reach easily 5/7k msg/seconds.
My setup is:

- 2 rabbitmq server 3.3.1 for HA (replicated), cluster (disk mode)

logstash conf:

```
rabbitmq {
   exclusive => false
   host => '...'
   password => '...'
   user => '...'
   vhost => 'logstash'
   # No ack will boost your perf
   ack => false   
   # Too high prefetch will slow down
   prefetch_count =>  50
   auto_delete => false
   durable => true
   exchange => "logstash"
   key => 'logstash.logs'

   queue => "logstash.logs"
   threads => 8
}
```

The may differences are 'ack: false', and prefetch_count => 50. 
if you have 4000 msg in the queue and 5 threads only two threads will process logs:

- thread 1: 2000 msg
- thread 2: 1000 msg
- thread 3-5: 0

Moreover I suggest to check if it's not your input stream that is slow:

- desactivate the indexer (only ship logs)
  -> the queue will be filled with millions messages
- deactivate the shipper, and reactivate the indexer
   -> monitor how fast it consumes the messages

Comment: Disabling the acknowledgement will result in lost logs.

Comment: Sending a ack after receiving the log before processing it can result in lost logs also. it depends what you are doing with the logs and the others steps in the log workflow (are they all reliable?).
Even with ack: True, he should get far more throughput.

Comment: @pagid losing logs occasionaly might not be a problem

Comment: @leozilla - true, but one should know the impact of their settings